# Is there a way to execute a .jar file through a shell script? (Raspbian)

Tags: java, linux, shell, minecraft

## **In gerneral**

### Mission

I want to run `java -jar -Xmx2G -Xms2G /home/pi/minecraft/server/spigot-1.15.2.jar` by clicking a desktop icon (or .desktop file).
When I type the commant into a terminal it works.

### Problem

The Terminal crashes.

## What i've tried

I created a .desktop File which executes a .sh file.
My .desktop File:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Spigot
Comment=
Exec=/home/pi/Desktop/launch_spigot_server.sh
Icon=/home/pi/Pictures/spigot.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
X-KeepTerminal=true
```

My .sh File:

```
#!/bin/bash
pkexec java -jar -Xmx2G -Xms2G /home/pi/minecraft/server/spigot-1.15.2.jar
```

("pkexec" because I think I need sudo rights to run a .jar file)

### Result

The Terminal actually opens and executes the .jar file and it says `Loading libraries, please wait...`, then throws some sort of Error and instantly crashes.

That is the farthest i've come in *3 hours*.

Comment: "I think I need sudo rights to run a .jar file" in general no, you don't.

Comment: Anyway, does that command line work when you launch it manually from any other directory or just from a specific directory?

Comment: Yes it works when I launch it manually from an other directory...

Comment: try `javaw` which is identical but doesn't require a console

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca in that case I kinda need to add sudo before the java -jar ... command. The server will start anyway but without sudo it displays some errors: `main ERROR Unable to locate appender "File" for logger config "root"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First go to the directory and then execute the java -jar... command

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/minecraft/server/
java -jar -Xmx2G -Xms2G spigot-1.15.2.jar
```